# Combining two boolean operators ( and or ) in if_else statement in R

Tags: r, dplyr, boolean

I am new to `R`, and trying to create a new variable based on multiple columns og two boolean operators in a `if_else()` statement. Is this possible?

What I want is: if Q16r1 is 5 AND OR Q16r2 is 5 AND OR Q16r3 is 5, then the new variable will take the value of 1, if else it'll take the value of 0.

I've tried this code:

```
mydata1 <- mydata %>%
  mutate(vet_ikke_dik = if_else(Q16r1 == 5 & | Q16r2 == 5 & | Q16r3 == 5, 1, 0))
```

But I get the following error code:

```
Error: unexpected '|' in:
"mydata1 <- mydata %>%
  mutate(vet_ikke_dik = if_else(Q16r1 == 5 & |"
```

Do anyone know what I can do to get the result I want? Would really appreciate some input!

Comment: What is `AND OR`? Are you talking about [inclusive disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)? If yes, it's the `|`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry I was not specific enough. What I want is basically if the value on Q16r1 is 5, and/or, the value on Q16r2 is 5, and/or ... etc. I read the article you sent, and if i understand it correctly it seems like that is what I'm after. "Given two propositions A and B, A or B is true if A is true, or if B is true, or if both A and B are true". The reason i wrote AND OR is because of this part of the quote "or if both A and B are true" <- that's what I want. So if change my code to only include | and not &, it will give me the result i want?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what the *inclusive*  disjunction is, the *exclusive* disjunction means *either A or B but not both*.